# what is package to import DJango TimeStampAwareModel

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make use of "TimeStampAwareModel" but I don't know what will be its package that I can import?

Please suggest me the package to use it?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a reusable package that provides `TimeStampAwareModel`.

[Searching GitHub](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=TimeStampAwareModel&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) brings up a few repositories that contain it, for example [django-newsfeed](https://github.com/ahmedsalman/django-newsfeed/blob/master/base/models.py).

It would probably be easier to define `TimeStampAwareModel` in your own models.py, rather than installing one of the repositories.